# Cakephp saveAll not saving multiple fields using the same field name

Tags: php, cakephp

I apologize in advance if this has been answered but I searched throughly and cannot find what I'm looking for.

I have a form with multiple inputs with the same name, but I'm unable to save the data into the database.

Below is my form code as well as my controller code.

Thanks in advance.
Charlie

register_your_card.ctp

```
                    echo $this->Form->input('RewardUser.0.reward_card_number', array('label' => '*Card number', 'class' => 'multipleInputs', 'maxlength' => '4'));
                echo $this->Form->input('RewardUser.1.reward_card_number', array('label' => '', 'class' => 'multipleInputs', 'maxlength' => '4', 'div' => false)); 
                echo $this->Form->input('RewardUser.2.reward_card_number', array('label' => '', 'class' => 'multipleInputs', 'maxlength' => '4', 'div' => false));
                echo $this->Form->input('RewardUser.3.reward_card_number', array('label' => '', 'class' => 'multipleInputs', 'maxlength' => '7', 'div' => false));
```

RewardUsersController.php

```
    public function register_your_card() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Rewards');
    $this->set('meta_keywords', 'Rewards');
    $this->set('meta_description', 'Rewards');                

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {   

        if ( !empty($this->request->data) ) {

            $this->RewardUser->create(); =
            if ($this->RewardUser->saveAll($this->request->data['RewardUser'])) {
                $lastInsertID = $this->RewardUser->getLastInsertID();
                $this->Session->write('currentUser', $lastInsertID);
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'rewardusers', 'action' => 'register_your_card_confirmation'));
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called saveMany that saves multiple rows for the same model, info here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

Try this:

```
public function register_your_card() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Rewards');
    $this->set('meta_keywords', 'Rewards');
    $this->set('meta_description', 'Rewards');                

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {   

        if ( !empty($this->request->data) ) {

            if ($this->RewardUser->saveMany($this->request->data['RewardUser'])) {
                $lastInsertID = $this->RewardUser->getLastInsertID();
                $this->Session->write('currentUser', $lastInsertID);
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'rewardusers', 'action' => 'register_your_card_confirmation'));
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is "saveMany" available in CakePHP 1.2?